# warning:assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, linux

Its quite a common question but I have not got my answer so asking it again.

I have structers defined as:

```
struct f_lock{
              int x;
              struct f_lock *next;
     };
```

Then say I have a function:

```
struct f_lock *new_node()
{
   struct f_lock *new_f_lock;
   .....
   return new_f_lock;
}
```

Which I call from another function:

```
struct f_lock *new_f_lock;
new_f_lock = new_node(); //This line gives the error warning:assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Would be grateull for help
Thanks

Comment: You most likely haven't declared a prototype of `new_node()` in scope. That being said, it's preferable you post code that people can use to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `function f_lock *new_node()` not `struct f_lock *new_node()`?

Comment: @Mike: in C, `function` is not reserved and has no special meaning. The original definition is correct. Without a `typedef`, the name of the type is `struct f_lock`; `f_lock` by itself is not defined

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074009/assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-cast)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you also get the error `implicit declaration of function ‘new_node’`? Because in that case, you probably forgot to declare `new_node` in the module where you're calling it. (If you're not getting that error, recompile with `-Wall` to turn more warnings on.)

Explanation of the warning message: if `new_node` has not been declared properly, the compiler will assume it returns `int`, which is a kind of default return type (for historical reasons).

Comment: I din't get the error but probably that is the case. For I have noth functions in the same module

Comment: @Juggler: It is almost always a good idea to turn compiler warnings up to maximum.

Comment: See also `-Werror` in the GCC manual, and use it to your advantage.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember getting this (rather misleading) error message once when I had forgotten to declare a function as taking `void` which is required in c (but not c++) for functions with no parameters:

```
struct f_lock *new_node()
{
   struct f_lock *new_f_lock;
   .....
   return new_f_lock;
}
```

Should be:

```
struct f_lock *new_node(void)
{
   struct f_lock *new_f_lock;
   .....
   return new_f_lock;
}
```