# Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast and other questions

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I just started learning C a few days ago and I'm having a bit of difficulties with pointers. I'm trying to convert a string to an array of integers. The little snipet below seems to be working but I'm getting a warning :

In function 'charToInt32' 
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 1 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|

The warning comes from the line

```
int32result[pos] = returnedInteger;
```

So I'm trying to understand what's the best solution. Should I use strncpy (but can I use strncpy for integers?) or something else or did I just completly misunderstand pointers?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>


    int charToInt32(char * clearText, unsigned int * int32result[])
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0, pos = 0;          /* Counters */
        int dec[4] = {24, 16, 8, 0};        /* Byte positions in an array*/
        unsigned int returnedInteger = 0;           /*   so we can change the order*/ 

        for (i=0; clearText[i]; i+=4) {
            returnedInteger = 0;
            for (j=0; j <= 3 ; j++) {
                returnedInteger |= (unsigned int) (clearText[i+j] << dec[j]) ;
            }

            int32result[pos] = returnedInteger;
            pos++;
        }
        return pos;
    }



    int main()
    {
        int i = 0;
        unsigned int * int32result[1024] = {0};
        char * clearText =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        printf(">>Clear: %s\n", clearText);
        charToInt32(clearText, int32result); // Do the conversion to int32.
        printf(">>Int32 converted: ");
        for (i=0; int32result[i]; i++)
            printf("%u ", (unsigned int) int32result[i]);
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Also, at the end of the program I have the following line:

```
printf("%u ", (unsigned int) int32result[i])
```

Casting int32result[i] to unsigned int is it the only solution to avoid another warning of using %u for an unsigned int * ?

I did check the other "assignment makes integer from pointer without cast" topics/question but I could not quite get a final answer from them.

Thank-you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074009/assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-cast)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
unsigned int * int32result[1024]
```

declares an array of 1024 `unsigned int` *pointers*.  I think you want an array of ints here instead

```
unsigned int int32result[1024]
```

You have a similar problem in `charToInt32` where the `unsigned int * int32result[]` argument specifies an array of `unsigned int` arrays.  You have a single array so could pass `unsigned int * int32result` instead (i.e. remove the `[]`).

The rest of your code should just work then.  Calls like

```
charToInt32(clearText, int32result);
```

are equivalent to

```
charToInt32(clearText, &int32result[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You declare `charToInt32` to take a pointer-to-pointer-to-`unsigned int` as an argument,

```
int charToInt32(char * clearText, unsigned int * int32result[])
```

but you use the argument as an array of `unsigned int`, so the argument should be

```
unsigned int *int32result
```

or equivalently (in a function declaration!! Not in general)

```
unsigned int int32result[]
```

And in `main`, it should be

```
unsigned int int32result[1024] = {0};
```

there you also have one level of pointers too many.

Answer (score 1):

The warning you get comes from the fact that you hare assigning an integer value to a pointer.

```
/* int32result is an array of POINTERS */
unsigned int * int32result[];
/* But returnedInteger is an int */
unsigned int returnedInteger = 0;
/*...*/
/* int32result[pos] is a pointer to an integer ...
 * Thus here, you assign a "pure" integer to a pointer,
 * hence the warning */
int32result[pos] = returnedInteger;
```

It is also totally sane that the compiler raises a warning when hitting the printf if you do not cast the value. As a matter of fact, pointers on common machines are often 32 or 64 bits, which is enough to avoid information loss during the *faulty* assignment. That is why your print statement should look like the program works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int * int32result[]
```

is an array of `unsigned int` pointers, so you are assigning the value to a pointer.