# warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] at malloc

Tags: c, malloc, compiler-warnings

```
90: if (links->info[links->length-1].paths = malloc(connections*sizeof(char*))==NULL) {
        perror("Malloc failed! Aborting execution\n"); exit(MF);}
for (j=0; j<connections; j++) {
93:    if (links->info[links->length-1].paths[j] = malloc(250*sizeof(char))==NULL) {
    perror("Malloc failed! Aborting execution\n"); exit(MF);}
}
```

where

```
 Link *links;
 int connections;
 typedef struct{               //Info of the link
   int inode;                  //I-node
   int prime_inode;            //Corresponding i-node
   int connections;            //Number of hard links
   int next_path;              //Where to put the next path
   char **paths;               //Paths that refer to the i-node
  } Link_info;

typedef struct {
   int length;                 //Number of links
   Link_info *info;            //The array of the link info
}Link;
```

And I get these warnings

```
 traverse.c:90:52: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 traverse.c:93:59: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

I want to make an array of strings which has "connections" # of cells and each string consists of 250 chars max. I wonder what's wrong with that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074009/assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-cast)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> links->info[links->length-1].paths = malloc(connections*sizeof(char*))==NULL
> ```

`==` takes precedence over `=`.
This should be

```
(links->info[links->length-1].paths = malloc(connections*sizeof(char*))) == NULL
```