# Warning -- assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, function, casting, return, warnings

I know that this was often asked but I read through a dozen of the questions and still have not found the solution. When compiling I get the warning:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

The code that this warning refers to is:

```
unsigned char *WebPrintReturnLine(BIO *bio) {

long int i;
unsigned int turn = 0;
unsigned char *ptr = 0;
int size;
unsigned char buffer[4096];

i = (long int) WebRead(bio, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
if( (ptr = (unsigned char *) malloc(strlen(buffer))) == 0 ) {
    printf("Error: Couldn't allocate memory in WebPrintReturnLine\n");
    return ptr;
}

//strlen does not care about '\0' but as array begin at 0 it nulifies
size = strlen(buffer);
//strcpy the buffer into the allocated memory
strcpy(ptr, buffer);
printf("%d\n", isend(buffer, sizeof(buffer)));

while( (i > 0) && (!isend(buffer, sizeof(buffer))) ) {
    i = (long int) WebRead(bio, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    size += strlen(buffer);
    if( (ptr = (unsigned char*) realloc(ptr, size)) == 0 ) {
        printf("Error: Couldn't reallocate memory in WebPrintReturnLine\n");
        ptr = 0;
        return ptr; 
    }//End if
    //Strcat the original string and the buffer together
    strcat(ptr, buffer);
}//End while

//Now finally print the line
printf("%s", ptr);

return ptr;
}
```

And this was called by:

```
unsigned char *ptr;    
if( (ptr = WebPrintReturnLine(bio)) == 0 )
    return -1;
```

I first wanted to short that code in this question but I had the efar that I may oversee something that causes this warning.

Comment: First off, your `strcpy` causes a buffer overflow because you don't allocate space for the null-terminator.

Comment: What's the type of `ptr` in the context `if( (ptr = WebPrintReturnLine(bio)) == 0 )`?

Comment: You need to have a declaration for `WebPrinReturnLine` before it is called.  Somewhere before your `if( (ptr = WebPrintReturnLine(bio)) == 0 )` line, you need a declaration like `unsigned char *WebPrintReturnLine(BIO *);`.

Comment: Don't use `0` in C - use `NULL`.

Comment: @PaulR better yet, just use `if (!(ptr = ...))`

Comment: What's the type of ptr in the context if( (ptr = WebPrintReturnLine(bio)) == 0 )? Sry forget to add this: it is also unsigned char

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: well that's a matter of taste/style - personally I prefer an explicit comparison with NULL - more verbose, but more readable (IMNVHO).

Comment: When I copy your code and add the required `#include` directives, I don't get that warning. The warning message you got should have included a line number, but you haven't told us which line of code it refers to.

Comment: @40two I had forgot to add this, it is also a pointer to an unsigned char (unsigned char *ptr; )

Comment: @John Bode I have a declaration in the header file, if that's it what you are asking for

Comment: @Keith Thompson If I run make I get the following warning: pop3.c:156:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
  if( !(ptr = WebPrintReturnLine(bio)))
            ^

Comment: So the warning is on the *second* code snippet in your question. The declaration of `WebPrintReturnLine` is not visible when you call it. Under C90 rules, the compiler assumes it returns `int` (incorrectly in this case). Under C99 rules, the call is illegal. You need to add a `#include` for the header that declares `WebPrintReturnLine`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: yep you're right I have forgotten it. Thanks to all of you. :-)

Comment: You would have gotten an answer more quickly if you had started with a small *complete* test case that reproduces the problem. We had to guess about the code you didn't show us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074009/assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-cast)

Answer (score 0):

So the warning is on the second code snippet in your question. The declaration of `WebPrintReturnLine` is not visible when you call it. Under C90 rules, the compiler assumes it returns `int` (incorrectly in this case). Under C99 rules, the call is illegal. You need to add a `#include` for the header that declares `WebPrintReturnLine`. –  Keith Thompson