# warning of makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

the function of swap get problem of augment transfer, the pointer is used but when the swap function is called, can not pass the argument(str) into the function. the warning is: 
passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default].

anyone can help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void swap(char *str);
void copy (const int size,  char array[3][5]);
int main(void) {
     char a[5];
     char b[5];
     char c[5];
     char dst[3][5];

     scanf("%s", a);
     swap(a);
     strcpy(dst[0], a);

     scanf("%s", b);
     swap(b);
     strcpy(dst[1], b);

     scanf("%s", c);
     swap(c);
     strcpy(dst[2], c);


    copy(3, dst);


    return 0;
}

void copy (const int size,  char array[3][5]){
    int i;
    char temp[5];
    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
        if(strcmp(array[i],array[i+1])<0)
        {
            strcpy(temp, array[i]);
            strcpy(array[i], array[i+1]);
            strcpy(array[i+1], temp);
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<3;i++){

        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }
    return;
}
void swap(char *str){
    char temp2;
    int j=0;
  for (;j<5;j++){
      if(strcmp(str[j],str[j+1])<0){
    strcpy(temp2, str[j]);
    strcpy(&str[j], str[j+1]);
    strcpy(str[j+1], temp2);
      }
  }
    return;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `strcmp` to do when you give it two `char`s? Or `strcpy` for that matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074009/assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-cast)

Comment: Be careful with your for-loop. if i == 2 => array[i+1] is array[3] which is out of range!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source of problem : Ist statement in the for loop of the swap function

```
  void swap(char *str)
    {
    //code
    //for_loop
    if(strcmp(str[j],str[j+1])<0)
    //code
    }
```

Here the problem is strcmp takes two string as its arguments, but by using str[j+1]
you are giving it a character.

Since you have
char *str; // pointer to array of characters (string)

"str[i+1]" means character at (i+1)th position in the string str.
Thats why its giving the error.