# pointer arithemetic: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, pointer-arithmetic

I found a following code while learning about `pointer arithmetic` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *p, *q, *r, a, b;
    p = &a;
    q = &b;
    p = p-q;             
    r = &a;
    r = (int*)(r-q);   
    printf("p = %p\n",p);
    printf("r = %p\n",r);
}
```

When I compiled the code I got the following warning:

```
test.c:7:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by   default]
         p = q-p;             
           ^
```

Now when I run the code, I got the following output:

```
p = 0x1
r = 0x1
```

Since the outputs are same, could anyone please explain the significance of the warning. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The difference between two pointers is not a pointer. It's a `ptrdiff_t`

Comment: And you would typically print that with by adding "t" to the `printf` format specification, something like "%td".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074009/assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-cast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substracting address from address, doesn't return address. It returns integer, which is a distance between those addresses.

N1570 - 6.5.6p9:

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined,
>   and its type (a signed integer type) is **ptrdiff_t** defined in the **stddef.h** header. ...

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting two pointers, it will give you an integer but you are storing the result in a pointer.

Comment: result is ptrdiff_t type which is a typedef of int

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting two pointers, it will give you an positive integer but you are storing the result in a pointer.So typecasting is mandatory here...

Do typecast as follows (Typecast must be for result of `p-q` ,Not for only p)

```
    p = (int*)(p-q);
```

By doing typecast like above, you will not get warning...

Comment: Please don't cast the result blindly, it may be very dangerous sometimes.

Comment: @Mohit Jain.. subtracting two addresses leads to one integer.If you don't want to typecast ,then don't store result in pointer.he tried to store result in pointer only.

Comment: Exactly my point. Don't store an integer in pointer variable. Pointers should store addresses. If you want to store pointer difference, use ptrdiff_t. Moreover it is not very senseful to take difference of two pointers which don't belong to same array. Typecasting is last solution to do something and it should be done very carefully.

Comment: @ANBUSANKAR need not to be a positive int. actually the result of difference of two pointers is ptrdiff_t type, which is int in nature (positive and negative both could occur) .