# Char* error in c

Tags: c, pointers

When I compile my code I get the following warning:

> main.c:8:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] Contents = getc(fp);

Why do I receive that warning?

```
char* readfile (char* fileName){
  char* contents;
  FILE* fp;
  fp = fopen(fileName,"r");
  while(getc(fp) != EOF){
    contents = getc(fp);
    *contents++;
  }    
return contents;
}
```

Comment: There are few issues: 1) allocate memory first, 2) call `getc` once per iteration, 3) move asterisk to the line before. Your stated problem stems from 3). Otherwise it is a duplicate question alike http://stackoverflow.com/q/2074009/673826

Comment: this, from the man page: "getc()  is equivalent to fgetc() except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates stream more than once."  is a very good reason to use 'fgetc()' rather than 'getc()'

Comment: when calling the system function: 'fopen()'  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful, and if ==NULL, then immediately use 'perror()' to have the associated system error message also be output (it will be more accurate, although very brief to indicate what actually went wrong)

Comment: inputting a single character at a time is very slow (lots and lots of kernel space execution time and very little user space execution time.)  suggest 1) use fseek() and ftell() to get size of file 2) char *contents = malloc(sizeoffile) 3) fread( contents, sizeoffile, 1, fp );   naturally, always check for errors on calls to system functions and may need to call fread() more than once to get whole file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error is fixed by changing

```
char* contents;
```

to

```
int contents;
```

However, to read the contents of the file, you need something along the lines of:

```
char* readfile (char* fileName)
{
   char* contents;
   FILE* fp;

   // Make sure to open in binrary mode.
   fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
   if ( fp == NULL )
   {
      return NULL;
   }

   // Go to the end of the file.
   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

   // Get the position. This indicates the size of the contents of the file.
   long size = ftell(fp);

   // Allocate enough memory to hold the contents.
   contents = malloc(size+1);

   // Rewind to the start of the file.
   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

   // Read the contents.
   size_t n = fread(contents, 1, size, fp);
   if ( n != size )
   {
      // Problem reading.
      // Deal with it.
   }

   // Terminate the string with a null character.
   contents[size] = '\0';

   // Return the contents.
   return contents;
}
```

Here's a `main` function that can be used to test the function.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   char* contents = NULL;
   if ( argc > 1 )
   {
      contents = readfile(argv[1]);

      // Use the contents.
      printf("%s", contents);

      // Deallocate memory.
      free(contents);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: why did you open the file in binary mode?

Comment: If you don't open in binary mode, you will get get a mismatch in the value returned by `ftell` and the number of characters that will be read by `fread`.

Comment: @Erk, `fread()` returns `size_t`. Thanks for prodding though.

Answer (score 0):

Although R Sahu's answer is technically, using an `int` where a `char*` is more accurate is probably not the best idea.

The problem, which Ghosh correctly pointed out, is that you are trying to assign to `contents` (a `char*`) the return value of `getc()` (an `int`). In order to fix this problem literally all you need to do is change line 6 to `*contents = getc(fp);`

However you also do not allocate any memory to `contents`. This would be done with `char * contents = new char*[MAXLENGTH];` where `MAXLENGTH` is the maximum length you expect to be stored in contents. If you do not know how long the character array will be, then use a resizable array.

I'm just going to leave [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) as a resource for you since it shows how to correctly write this code, and is IMO the best book on C ever written.

Answer (score -1):

The main issue is

```
 contents = getc(fp);
```

as `getc()` returns an `int` and you're trying to store that in a char *`. You should change

```
char* contents;
```

to

```
int contents;
```

Having said that,

1. You should check for `fopen()` success before using the returned file pointer.
2. You're calling `fgetc()` twice, and only the return value from the second call is *used*.

---

EDIT:

Keeping in mind the whole function in your code, if you make the `contents` an `int`, you'll end up only saving the latest read value from the file. If you want to read the whole file content, and return the same to the caller, you should make the following changes

- Take the character pointer, like `char * contents = NULL;`
- Allocate memory dynamically, using `malloc()` and family. The size to be allocated can be obtained by using `ftell()` on the file pointer returned by `fopen()`. One  more element is required for null-termination of the string.
- Read the file content, either one by one using `fgetc()` or all at a time using `fread()`. After the reading, null-terminate the array.
- return the pointer to the caller.

Also, in the caller, once the usage of the returned pointer is over, don't forget to `free()` the memory.

Comment: This answer will read the whole file, but only keep the last character read to pass back to the caller.   I think the OPs plan is to keep the whole file contents in memory and pass back a pointer to the saved contents of the file

Comment: @user3629249 how about now?