# warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] in C program

Tags: c

I can not solve this problem: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] -> auxcandidate = alpha[pos]

Here's my code:

```
char* getkey(int minimo, int maximo, int alphalen, int index, char alpha[]);   
int main()  
    {  
        int minimo = 2;
        int maximo = 2;
        char *alpha = "abc";
        int alphalen = strlen(alpha);

        char *candidata;

        printf("La candidata es: ");
        candidata = getkey(minimo, maximo, alphalen, 5, alpha);
        //printf(" %c", candidata); 
        //if (candidata = "bc")
        //{}
        return 0; 
    }

    char* getkey (int minimo, int maximo, int alphalen, int index, char alpha[])  
    {  
        int cociente, residuo, cont;
        int i = 0;
        char cand[maximo+1];

        char* auxcandidate;

        while (index != 0)
        {
            cociente = index / alphalen;
            residuo = index%alphalen;
            cand[i] = residuo;
            index = cociente;
            i+=1;
        }

        for (cont=i-1; cont>=0; cont--)  
        {   
            int pos = cand [cont];
            auxcandidate = alpha[pos];      
        }
        return auxcandidate;
    }
```

Can someone explain these warning?

Comment: Ask yourself this: "What is `auxcanidate`? What is `alpha`? What is `alpha[pos]`?" Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074009/assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-cast)

Comment: Why is your function duplicated?

Answer (score 4):

Please note the following line:

```
auxcandidate = alpha[pos];
```

Alpha(pos)  is not an address (pointer)  but the value in that location, and you are trying to write it to a char pointer, so in fact you conduct casting, and that is the source for the warning

Answer (score 0):

Just like @dear_tzvi said, that line is the source of the warning.

You should use:

```
auxcandidate = &alpha[pos];
```

If you want the auxcandidate variable to point to that index

Comment: I want auxcandidate variable returns "bc". i don not know how to do it.

Comment: I didn't read you entire program, but if the assignment happens when pos is 1, it will work